# The control of up and down or left and right key on keyboard using jquery in Android

Tags: android, jquery

I am using jquery and jquery mobile to develop the program.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
                        if ( e.which == 19)  { //  get the up key
                        alert("111111");
                        })
```

I check online. It is said only Android versions 4.1.1 can support keyboard. Otherwise I need to write about the return value.

Who knows how to use jquery set the keyboard?

Thanks in advance!